# Powershell - How to parse the response

Tags: azure, powershell, api

All, I am new to powershell and trying with a simple powershell script which invokes a REST API and get the value.

The scenario is, Using powershell will trigger a POST request and get the response value and using that value as a parameter in another GET API request.

POST :

```
$Params = @{"id"=38}
$headers = @{
Authorization="Bearer XXXXXX"



$getrunid=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://abctech.com/api/2.0/run 
-Body ($Params|ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType application/json -Headers 
$headers
```

The response will be 2 value. E.g., id=10, queue=15

I am now taking only the id response.

GET:

```
$getrunidvalue=$getrunid.id

$getcheck=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 
https://abctect.com/api/2.0/jobs/runs/get?id=$getrunidvalue -ContentType 
application/json -Headers $headers

echo $getcheck
```

This gives the result as below.

```
id1                  : 38
run_id                  : 1
number_in_job           : 6
original_attempt_run_id : 217
state                   : @{life_cycle_state=TERMINATED; 
result_state=SUCCESS; state_message=}
task                    : @{notebook_task=}
```

From this result I need to take the value of result_state.

I am not finding ideas on how to do that, can someone help.

Thanks

Expected result would be the result_state SUCCESS or FAILED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `state` is a hashtable that contains an entry `result_state` that you want to retrieve. You can access it using:

```
$getcheck.state.result_state
```